# Javascript set attribute value error: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning to use javascript, and i am trying to have some text alternate between "bruh" and "moment" after every click. I am trying to store the text's state in attribute "data-state", which (should) alternate between 1 and 2, but i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" on line 12.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>bruh moment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {text-align: center; color: blue;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funcClick(){
            var myParagraph = document.getElementById("myp");
            if (myParagraph.data-state == 1){
                myParagraph.innerHTML = "bruh";
                myParagraph.data-state = 2; //ERROR IS HERE
            }else{
                myParagraph.innerHTML = "click again i dare you";
                myParagraph.data-state = 1;
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="myp"; data-state=1;> bruh </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="funcClick()">
        Click me
    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

> expected:
>   click button -> "moment"
>   click button -> "bruh"
>   click button -> "moment"
>   click button -> "bruh"
>
> actual:
>   [Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment]
>   click button -> "bruh"
>   [Uncaught ReferenceError: funcClick is not defined]
>   click button -> "bruh"
>   [Uncaught ReferenceError: funcClick is not defined]

here is the actual web page in case it helps http://3863.us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have hyphens `-` in a variable name - use `[]` brackets:

```
myParagraph["data-state"] = 2;
```